# Replace last entered @ with span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want replace a tag via click function. But right now my whole `@` are getting replaced by my function. I just want to replace last entered `@`. I can find last `@` by using of `lastIndexOf` but the problem is user can entered in between of text. So here come issue, how we know that position of last entered `@`. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seuok4r5/3/)

```
<div class="text" contenteditable="true"></div>
<div class="tags">
    <span>tag</span>
        <span>jimmy</span>
        <span>mike</span>
        <span>jonny</span>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$('.tags span').click(function(){
var html= $('.text').html()
var dd= html.replace('@','<span class="tag">'+$(this).text()+'</span>')
$('.text').html(dd);
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try with `lastIndexOf` and `substr` methods like this http://jsfiddle.net/seuok4r5/7/

Comment: I think you need to provide the updated jsfiddle version. You're linked to OPs address.

Comment: Actually, it should be `i > -1` to allow matching of the first `@`

Comment: You are right I'll update fiddle. @YummyUnicornRainbowTails

Comment: might be my question is not clear, I want to replace last entered @. Last entered means not the last of the line. Its mean last @ entered by the user. for example. ex. "i want to tag @you". "i @ want to tag @you" . in this case last entered text is followed by i

Answer (score 1):

I have also tried something, have a look mate

```
$('.tags span').click(function(){
var html= $('.text').text();
var dd= html.replace(html[html.lastIndexOf('@')],'<span class="tag"contenteditable="true">'+$(this).text()+'</span>&nbsp')
$('.text').html(dd);
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/punkhaa/796nsvsv/1/

Answer (score 0):

I would be recording the last cursor position via a `keyup` event - that way you always know which @ symbol you need to be modifying.

```js
var lastPos = null;
$('.text').keyup(function() { 
  // Get the cursor position, and record it
  lastPos = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startOffset;
  console.log("Cursor: " + lastPos);
});

$('.tags span').click(function(){
  
  // find the first occurance of @ before the lastPos
  var html= $('.text').html()
  var index = html.lastIndexOf("@", lastPos - 1); // find any @ before the cursor position
  console.log("@Index: " + index);
  
  if (index >= 0) {
    var tag = '<span class="tag">'+ $(this).text() + '</span>&nbsp;';

    // slice the result, to remove the @, and add the span
    html = html.substr(0, lastPos - 1) + tag + html.substr(lastPos + 1, html.length);
    
    // replace in the div
    $('.text').html(html);
  }

})
```

```css
.text {border:solid 1px #000; height:100px}
.tags{ padding-top:10px}
.tags span{background:#ff0000;color:#fff; display:inline-block; padding:5px}

.tag{background:#ff0000;color:#fff; display:inline-block; padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text" contenteditable="true"></div>

<div class="tags">
    <span>tag</span>
        <span>jimmy</span>
        <span>mike</span>
        <span>jonny</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code only run for the first time @@. If continue typing with "@" at the end of text, it's not changed!

Comment: @MrNeo check Carlos' response in the top rated comment - this is exactly the functionality he is after.